# Background Image UploadField doesn't show in the CMS

Tags: php, silverstripe

On a SilverStripe CMS website I have a custom footer add-on code that I'd like to extend so I can upload a background image in the CMS. The code seems fine, but the added field is no where to be found in the CMS.

This is my code:

```
class CustomFooter extends DataExtension {

    static $db = array(
        'FooterContent' => 'HTMLText'
    );

    public static $has_one = array(
        'Logo' => 'Image',
        'BGImage' => 'Background Image'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $this->extend('updateCMSFields', $fields);
        return $fields;
    }

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', new HTMLEditorField('FooterContent', 'Footer Content'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new UploadField('Logo', 'Company Logo'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new UploadField('BGImage', 'Background image'));
    }
}
```

Weirdly enough, both image upload fields don't show where as the Content tab show and functions as expected.

Why aren't the `UploadField`s displaying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
public static $has_one = array(
"Logo"=>"Image",
"BGImage"=>"Background Image"
);
```

looks pretty weird. The `$has_one`array has the relation name as key and the class name of the relation as value, I doubt a classname with space in the name is allowed. So I'd try something like

```
public static $has_one = array(
"Logo"=>"Image",
"BGImage"=>"Image"
);
```

then run a `dev/build?flush` and check in the database if your table has a `LogoID` column and a `BGImageID`column for the has one relations.

The field generation looks ok, it should work as is.

Comment: The biggest problem was the Root set in my UploadField.....

The code works, what i did, i pointed the UploadField to the Man and not my Footer Tab....

$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new UploadField('BGImage', 'Background image'));

I was suppose to say: 

$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', new UploadField('BGImage', 'Background image'));